# iPhone/iPad webview - Event fired after HTML is rendered?

Tags: iphone, ipad, webview

I have a webView which displays a local html file loaded with jQuery etc. The page takes about 2 seconds to render.

Is there an event in the WebViewDelegate that says, "The page is rendered"?

Once I pass the HTML to the webview control returns immediately as the webview sets off working to render in som background task.

I need to know when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `webViewDidFinishLoad`. Here's Apple's documentation: **[UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)**.

Comment: Merci, that is what I am looking for.